# stein structure of cotangent bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact manifold with dimension $\geq 3$. By a theorem of ELIASHBERG,

the cotangent bundle of $M$ admits an integrable complex structure $J$ such that

$(T^*M, J)$ is a stein manifold. My question is: Define the map $f$ by

$$f: T^*M \rightarrow T^*M, (x,v) \rightarrow (x, -v), x \in M, v \in T_x^*M$$.
Is it true that $f$ is an anti-holomorphic map with respect to the complex structure $J$ on $T^*M$?

Comment: Isn't it holomorphic? The function $\mathbb{C}^n\times\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n\times\mathbb{C}^n$ given by $(z, w) \mapsto (z, -w)$ is holomorphic.

Comment: But the complex structure on $T^*M$ may be complicated and it is different from your example?

Comment: I see. I don't understand what you mean by "$(T^*M, J)$ is a stein manifold". Isn't $J$ an integrable almost complex structure on $M$? If so, it is a vector bundle endomorphism of $TM$ such that $J^2 = -\operatorname{id}$. I don't see how this gives the manifold $T^*M$ a complex structure. Could you include some more information about the theorem of Eliashberg you are referring to?

Comment: See Theorem 1.2 in the unpublished book "symplectic geometry of stein manifolds"

Comment: The problem I see here is that the construction is rather abstract, and doesn't give you a concrete complex structure, but rather the isotopy class of $J$. What I think can be asked is whether there is a representative in that class such that the map you ask for is holomorphic/antiholomorphic.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: When $\dim M$ is odd, the map he defines reverses the orientation, so in general it can't be holomorphic. As for the theorem he mentions, take a look at the recent book by Cieliebak and Eliashberg. The theorem he refers to simply states that Stein structure in dimension $\ge6$ are obstructed by topology (existence of a Morse function with critical points of index less than half of the dimension of the manifold) and obstruction theory (existence of an almost-complex structure).

Comment: As you said, it shows there is "an" almost complex structure, so there is most probably a family of such. Some of these may be symmetric and some may not. I belive the steps of proof shows that one can respect the symmetry through the construction. Especially becuase the pluri sub-harmonic function can be chosen to be symmetric.

Comment: By the way, if you want to export such complex structure to a neighborhood of lagrangian manifold M in some symplectic manifold X such that X admits an anti- symplectic involution $\phi$ with $Fix(\phi)=M$, via Weinstein neighborhood theorem, some where in my thesis i showed that there is symplectomorphism that respects the anti- symplectic involution.